# Add more partition to NVMe SoftRAID CentOS 7

Tags: centos, raid

I have SoftRAID setup on CentOS on my NVMe Drive (2x1TB) . Issue is I only provisioned 80GB and I now want to provision more for additional space. Can someone please help me do this. Here is output of `lsblk`:

```
nvme0n1                                               259:1    0 894.3G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1                                           259:3    0   511M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2                                           259:5    0  78.1G  0 part
│ └─md2                                                 9:2    0  78.1G  0 raid1 /
└─nvme0n1p3                                           259:7    0   511M  0 part  [SWAP]
nvme1n1                                               259:0    0 894.3G  0 disk
├─nvme1n1p1                                           259:2    0   511M  0 part
├─nvme1n1p2                                           259:4    0  78.1G  0 part
│ └─md2                                                 9:2    0  78.1G  0 raid1 /
└─nvme1n1p3                                           259:6    0   511M  0 part  [SWAP]

[root@cloud963 ~]# cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name

 259        0  937692504 nvme1n1
 259        2     523264 nvme1n1p1
 259        4   81918976 nvme1n1p2
 259        6     523264 nvme1n1p3
 259        1  937692504 nvme0n1
 259        3     523264 nvme0n1p1
 259        5   81918976 nvme0n1p2
 259        7     523264 nvme0n1p3
   9        2   81918912 md2
   8        0 5860522584 sda
   8        1 5860520960 sda1
   8       16 5860522584 sdb
   8       17 5860520960 sdb1
   9        4 5860388864 md4
 253        0   52428800 dm-0
 253        1  314572800 dm-1
 253        2   20971520 dm-2
 253        3   20971520 dm-3
```

Comment: Could you also include the contents of `/proc/partitions` so that we see what lies where?

Comment: which version of centOS?

Answer (score 0):

### Too long, didn't read version:

You could look up "how to use `mdadm` to create a new raid partition", but you're really not doing yourself a favor having individual RAID partitions. Instead, use a volume manager to make the most of your space - and maximize the lifetime of your SSDs, too, as they live longer with properly deduplicated / discarded blocks.

### The whole story

So, especially when you do something with multiple disks and lots of storage, it's clever if you have a volume manager.

Let's do the following:

- Create a new mirrored block device (so Linux takes care of the data redundancy, as it does now on nvme0n1p2/nvme1n1p2)
- Create a space from which you can, at will, create, delete, resize, snapshot volumes (a volume is basically a partition, but a more flexible term). This is called a *volume group*.
- Create, within that space, a so-called *thin pool*, which just means that volumes within that space only occupy the space they actually need (and deleting files will give you memory to use for other volumes).
- Create, within that thin pool, a large volume and format it with a modern file system that supports thin provisioning (i.e. tells the volume manager when a sector of storage is no longer used, so that it can count that as available storage)
- Finally, add that volume to fstab and demonstrate it can be used.

This all has the purpose of you never having to buy an external drive to copy files over in case you need to shift anything, and that backups to or from your RAID goes smoothly and space-efficiently (that's money) as possible.

### How to do it

I'd do the following:

1. Use your favorite partitioning tool¹ to add a new partition each on nvme0n1 and nvme1n1. I'll call them $PA and $PB below, realistically they'd be /dev/nvme0n1p4 and /dev/nvme1n1p4², respectively, probably.
   Make them use all the free space (or maybe leave twice your RAM space in free space and enlarge your swap later, this seems to be very little swap space). Don't format them here (or use "LVM physical volume" as format).
2. create a RAID1 from these two partitions (I assume `/dev/md3` does not currently exist; check with `ls /dev/md*` and pick a number that's not there yet)
   `sudo mdadm --create /dev/md3 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 $PA $PB`
   We've now created a mirrored block device /dev/md3.
3. create an LVM2 (*Logical Volume Manager*) volume group encompassing that fresh RAID block device:

   `sudo vgcreate raidvg /dev/md3`

   We've now got a volume group called "raidvg".
4. Let's create a thin pool in that volume group:

   `sudo lvcreate -l 100%FREE -T raidvg/thinpool`

   We've now got a thin pool called "thinpool". It fills all the volume group's space, which in turn means it occupies the full RAID volume you created in 1.
   That's great, now you can use that very flexibly!

So, these were the preparations for you to be able to create arbitrarily many volumes in there. Let's do that.

4. Let's finally create a volume in that, which gets a "virtual" size of say, 100 GB³

   `sudo lvcreate -V 100G -T raidvg/thinpool -n firstvolume`

   We now have a (thinly provisioned) volume "firstvolume". You can find it as block device `/dev/mapper/raidvg-firstvolume`.
5. Create a file system on that. You get to choose between XFS and btrfs (state of: June 2021) when you want that the file system can tell the underlying that it's not using some blocks, so that you can reuse space. Under CentOS: XFS.

   `sudo mkfs.xfs /dev/mapper/raidvg-firstvolume`
6. mount that! First, make a mountpoint, say `/catpictures`

   `sudo mkdir /catpictures`
   `sudo mount /dev/mapper/raidvg-firstvolume /catpictures`
   Tadah, `/catpictures` can now be used. Adjust that folder's permissions to your liking, if you want someone else than root to put things in there.
7. (optional, but enables mount at boot) Edit your /etc/fstab to include that! , then add 
   `/dev/mapper/raidvg-firstvolume /catpictures  xfs noatime 0 0`

   to /etc/fstab.

That's it, really!

If you later want to add another volume, you'd only have to run

```
sudo lvcreate -V 100G -T raidvg/thinpool -n name_of_new_volume
```

You can look for mark space not used in the file systems explictly by running `sudo fstrim` on the mounted filesystem (but your CentOS probably also does that automatically once in a while).

You can delete volumes using

```
sudo lvremove /dev/mapper/raidvg-name_of_volume_to_be_deleted.
```

If you find out there's more than 100GB of cat pictures, you can do

```
sudo lvextend -L200G -r /dev/mapper/raidvg-firstvolume
```

to increase the volume's size to 200 GB (or rather, it's maximum size – this is still thinly provisioned and only uses the SSD space it actually uses to store data). The `-r` switch tells it to tell XFS about the size change. This all can be done online, i.e. while you've got your `/catpictures` mounted!

LVM thin pools have many cool features. Since you're using RAID1, you probably care about data archival – *snapshots* allow you to keep a version of your data as it is *today* and use that as another volume separately, without duplicating the data that doesn't change.

---

¹ `blivet-gui` from EPEL if you're on CentOS 8 is very good, if you're on CentOS 7, use `gparted`

² You should probably literally `export PA=/dev/nvme0n1p4 ; export PB=/dev/nvme1n1p4`, then you don't have to type these longish strings all over again

³ This space is not used *right now*, you can have *more* thinly-provisioned memory than you actually have space. We could have used 5 TB as virtual space! The space gets actually assigned to your volume as the file system uses it. see `sudo lvs` to see how the usage percentage is. You'll only run into problems when you try to actually save more data than you have space – then you'll have to add more SSDs to your system, because LVM can do much, but not magic :)